# Is it possible to simplify trycatch block?

Tags: c#, exception

Sometimes feel like a try catch block is just an extra scope around an already existing scope.

Original:

```
public void Method()
{
    try
    {
        // do something
        ...
    }
    catch (CustomException e)
    {
        DoSomethingWithCustomException(e);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        DoSomethingWithException(e);
    }
}
```

Simplified:

```
public void Method()
{
    // do something
    ...
    catch (CustomException e) => DoSomethingWithCustomException(e); 
    catch (Exception e) => DoSomethingWithException(e); 
}
```

In my opinion the "try" part of the block is meaningless if you use it for the entire scope. And you can use the original syntax beside this. This syntax can be useful in foreach or any other loop.

So is it possible enable a syntax like this?

Comment: There are various proposals to reduce the amount of syntax in a try/catch, but they don't have much traction among the language developers.

Comment: I don't get the point of asking a question with "No" as answer

Comment: It isn't currently possible, and I sorta question the benefit. I mean, I get that it would be less typing... but generally try/catches shouldn't take up entire method bodies (although of course sometimes they can/should, and that's ok). It also hurts maintainability IMO, as it hides the fact that something is being caught until the very end (so I disagree with `..the "try" part of the block is meaningless..`).

Comment: One doesn't need to start a method with `try { ... }`. There can be `/* some code */ try { ... } catch { ... }`. Now, removing the `try` part, you can't make a difference between what is in `/* some code */` and what is inside the `try`. This can be a problem is you have a `finally` part. In example, if `/* some code */` returns something, the `finally` shouldn't be executed

Comment: Maybe they implement it in C# 9, they already made the switch-case like that, so why not try-catch. Maybe if you initialize the method like that: Method() : try {}, so the compiler still knows what's in the try-block (the entire method, except catch-blocks)

Comment: I wouldn't think it's very common at all to be placing a try/catch around the insides of entire methods. If that's happening all over your code base, I'd lean towards some code smell going on.

Comment: @CodeStranger Well you could create a try-catch method only for that. I mean, as example the "Enter a number". Instead of doing "try { Convert.ToInt32(...)}..."
You can create a method ConvertToNumber(string s), I already do that

Answer (score 2):

> So is it possible enable a syntax like this?

Not in the current version of C#. You can always suggest a language feature [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang), but first search the existing proposals to see if it's been proposed already.

A quick search for "catch" in the issues led to this almost identical proposal:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/908

Note that it has 1 upvote and 15 downvotes. There's only one comment on it, but it gives at least some feedback as to the viability of the feature.

You might also look at third-party libraries like [PostSharp](https://doc.postsharp.net/exception-handling) that can inject exception handling at a method level.

Comment: Note that there are already **many** proposals like this -- please search for existing proposals before adding your own.

Comment: (In no particular order: [#908](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/908), [#616](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/616), [#968](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/968), [#1015](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1015), [#2734](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2734), [#980](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/980), [#1567](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1567), [#2151](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2151), [#1210](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1210), and more)